# Can not make DatePicker in Android

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker

I have just written an Android program, which consists in a DatePicker, but it doesn't work.

Java Code is :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        CurDateTv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Picker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
        btnChangeDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            Picker.init(year, month,day, onChangedListener())
            }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
            return true;

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
   public void onDateChangedListener(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
       CurDateTv2.setText(new String Builder()
               .append(dayOfMonth).append("/").append(monthOfYear + 1)
               .aapend("/").append(year).append(" "));

   }
}
```

And the layout is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Current Date"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="08/08/2016"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
                />

<CalendarView
                android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Unfortunately, I don't know Java very well, so I can't identify where the error is.
I really hope that you can help me.

Comment: Where you have declare this 'Picker' variable and second every initialization of resources should only be after setContentView() method, you have initialize resource first and then call setContentView() so change it

Comment: Declare your picker  i.e Picker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.calendarView1); 

and other variables below

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a DialogFragment class in Date and Time Pickers to make it usable across the application and to easy deal with the pickers..

See this official developers.android guide:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Answer (score 1):

```
            //Initialize the variables
            Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date;
            DatePickerDialog d1;



                //To be written in oncreate method

        //define
        date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        //It is a function that sets the value to the edittext after selection
                updateLabel();
            }
        };


    //onClick listener to the button which open the calendar
    fromDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            d1= new DatePickerDialog(className.this, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            d1.show();
        }
    });

    //finally the function 
    private void updateLabel() {
        String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

    //Display the selection
        fromDateEdit.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not Required CalenderView. It's Edit text to possible.

Refer:

http://androidopentutorials.com/android-datepickerdialog-on-edittext-click-event/